# Which is more efficient as the default argument: None or lambda x: x

Tags: python, performance, optimization

Out of curiousity, what's more efficient when calling the following function without the second argument? Using an if statement:

```
def f(elements, l=None):
    for el in elements:
        ...
        if l:
            el = l(el)
        ...
```

or using a lambda?

```
def f(elements, l=lambda x: x):
    for el in elements:
        ...
        el = l(el)
        ...
```

I would use the second variant anyway, for when the function argument is provided, but I am nonetheless interested which one is more efficient when running with just the default value.

Comment: i feel like the first variant is way more readable (also the doc will look nicer). if you are concerned about efficiency you can always put the `if` statement before (outside) the loop... compare e.g. with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?sorted#sorted) in the standard library that has exactly the same interface.

Comment: running `%timeit` the clear winner is the one with the if statement

Comment: @Nullman I suppose that's (1) not inside REPL and (2) Cpython? Should anything different be expected from other implementations (PyPy)?

Comment: @user3496846 im in the pydevcosole that comes with pycharm, and ive just realized that i have no idea on how to check with flavor of python 3.6  i have, i think its cpython

Comment: Apart from the question of efficiency, OP's second approach suffers one weakness that the first approach does not: The first approach will work gracefully regardless of whether you pass `None`, or don't pass anything at all, as the second argument. The second approach will fail if `None` is passed as the second argument, which, though a programming error, is a likely one.

Comment: The second version is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in my comment: i recommend you use

```
def f(elements, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = lambda x: x
    for el in elements:
        el = l(el)
```

this way you only have on additional `if` statement, so no performance penalty (complexity-wise at least) - as opposed to your first example where you need to test in every iteration of the loop.

and if you compare e.g. with [`sorted(iterable, *, key=None, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?sorted#sorted) from the standard library, this seems to be the more standard interface (note `key=None` which also needs to be a callable - just as in your case). and this will make the documentation look nicer and more standard.

or, to improve efficienty if `l` is indeed `None`:

```
def f(elements, l=None):
    if l is None:
        for el in elements:
            ...
    else:
        for el in elements:
            el = l(el)
            ...
```

Comment: And the reasoning…?

Comment: @deceze i understood the OP was concerned about the `if` statement causing an efficiency penalty when inside the loop. and (as mentioned in the comment above - but maybe that should also go into the answer - that the doc will look nicer and more readable).

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this information; comments are eligible for deletion at any time. Besides, your answer should be self-contained.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why this is better than just writing `l=lambda x: x`. Seems to add an extra if statement, that's all.

Comment: as i mentioned, i feel its 'better' with regard to readability/convention. and it adds only very few instructions per call, so its pretty much as efficient.

Comment: dont forget that `if` statements are way cheaper than function calls, and lambdas are functions even if they dont look like them

Comment: @hiroprotagonist well that's nice, but I was more worried about the performance - testing, reasoning, optimization. Accoriding to some quick Nullman's result in the comments, the if-one should be preferrable. My question is why.